# Is a Wifi antenna both a transmitter and a receiver?

Tags: wireless, electromagnetism, wifi

I only have one antenna on my Wifi card so I am assuming it is both the receiver and the transmitter, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Does it constantly switch between being a receiver to being a transmitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a T/R (transmit/receive) switch and yes, virtually all antennas can be used to transmit and recieve (some at the same time if the spacing between transmit and receive frequencies is sufficient and deep filtering is involved).

Comment: So the router has one Master 'clock' and all Wifi Devices connected to it gets synchronized ?

Comment: I can't answer that off the top of my head. The term "master clock" implies that there can be only one. I think you'll need to google how a wifi syncs up with receivers but ceertainly it has a T/R switch.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks: that ("master clock") is a different issue. You're now asking about how the channel is divided over time. There's a rather complicated scheme, but basically the router assigns time slots to devices. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_access_method#Time_division_multiple_access_.28TDMA.29 for more.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff was just about to Google it when you beat me to it :) Thanks.